# How to delete Firebase data that are created by Firebase itself?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

When we add some data into Firebase Realtime DB, and try to delete them, we encounter some problems that Firebase is getting them back although we delete them. How can I get rid of this. Automatically, Firebase is getting back all data that we have just deleted. Thank you in advance

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't write any data on its own. There is always some application code, or an Extension, that does that. Please edit your question to include enough information for us to reproduce the behavior you are seeing. E.g. if you create a new project in Firebase, what steps do you need to take to get the data to re-appear?

Comment: Could the recycler view be the reason? I retrieved the data from Firebase first to the page containing recycler view and, I'm transferring the data directly from this recycler view to another page, not from Firebase again. Then, I m removing the data in Firebase and I don't see this data in Firebase. However, if I come to the page, I am seeing the data again that I've just removed from Firebase. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Instead of describing in words in a comment, please edit your question so include the steps and code necessary. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also respond with @.